# Url Redirection based on the Device

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

What we need to do regarding the mobile and app redirection is if a person enters the site from a mobile device?

1)      If the device uses IOS (except IPAD) then suggest that the user should download the mobile app. By clicking on the link the user is redirected to appstore. If the user clicks on “Skip app download” forward the user to m.example.com

2)      If the device uses Android, then suggest that the user should download the mobile app. By clicking on the link the user is redirected to google play. If the user clicks on “Skip app download” forward the user to m.example.com

3)      If the user enters through any mobile device, just forward them to the mobile site m.abc.com.

4)      If the device is all other than above: forward to m.example.com. All links should be opened in m.example.com format. The links should be converted to:

a.       If a person visits www.example.com/ViewVacancy.aspx?ID=66880 the link should be converted to http://m.example.com/vacancy.aspx?name=66880

b.      If a person visits any other page from abc.com from mobile. He should be redirected to http://m.example.com

Comment: you are looking for exact solution of your task, asking for someone to do your work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: redirect the user if he browses site abc.com from mobile, ios, android to mobile site m.abc.com

Comment: Still not a question.

Comment: no, usng asp.net forms

Comment: @DotnetSparrow That is a specification. What we want is a question. What have you tried? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @MattEllen: I am new to mobile redirection. I dont know where to put this redirection code, in master page, in html or in js or in global.asax, thats why I posted all possible scanerios. it is not a specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Global.asax`

**Add this following Code:**

```
  protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            // Your Logic
        }
        if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
        {
            //Create a list of all mobile types
            string[] mobiles =
            new[]
            { "midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo",
            "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource",
            "240×320", "opwv", "chtml",
            "pda", "windows ce", "mmp/",
            "blackberry", "mib/", "symbian",
            "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi",
            "phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio",
            "SIE-", "SEC-", "samsung", "HTC",
            "mot-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony"
            , "alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx",
            "NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx",
            "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch",
            "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java",
            "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi",
            "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda",
            "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo",
            "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "dddi",
            "moto", "iphone"
            };

            //Loop through each item in the list created above
            //and check if the header contains that text
            foreach (string s in mobiles)
            {
                if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].
                ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
                {
                    //Your Logic
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Hope this may helpful.,

Comment: If you want to add any new device names, you can add it. In `string[] mobiles = new[] {`. But the Device name should be correct. I mean like `"iphone"`

Comment: It should work. Keep on Trying.

Comment: It is redirecting to abc.com/m.abc.com instead of just abc.com with    if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            Response.Redirect("m.abc.com");
        }

Comment: Hi @RJK: Sorry for late response. I am facing an issue with the code which you sent. Can you please check here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105653/site-redirection-to-mobile-site-using-asp-net-and-application-acquirerequeststat